# Unable to get the correct location within indoor environment using with only WIFI

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I wrote a program that provides the user's position with in a building but not the actual position . I Know that Gps does not provide high accurate result with in building . My code is as follows:

```
public class Internet extends Service implements LocationListener {

Context context;
LocationManager locationManager;

public Internet(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

}

Location findMeInternet() {
    Boolean isInternet = false;
    Location location;
    isInternet = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (isInternet) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3, 1, this);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            return location;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

 //other override methods with empty bodies .

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is location in not actual location !

Answer (score 0):

Try GPS provider instead of NetWORK provider ,

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, this);
if (locationManager != null) 
{
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) 
    {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

    }
}
```

Make sure that device GPS is enabled. (If someone needs to downvote, please mention the reason also)

Comment: Are you sure Gps return correct location in building  ??

Comment: GPS is more reliable than Network, refer this ,  https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/05/android-gps-positioning-location-strategies/